# Reconciling total internal reflection and the evanescent Wave

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, geometric-optics, waveguide

I understand that light is guided in a dielectric waveguide via total internal reflection. My question is regarding the origin of power contained in the evanescent field traveling along the direction of propagation.

From Fresnel equation we get that the reflection coefficient is %100 for angles above or equal to the critical angle as shown in the following figure: 
[image]

It is clear from the figure that no power is transmitted from medium 1 to medium 2.

However, from dielectric waveguide theory we know that some power is contained in medium 2 and we define the *confinement factor* which is a measure of amount of power confined in the core of the waveguide compared to the power contained in the evanescent field. The confinement factor is defined as following:

$$\Gamma = \dfrac{\int_{-L_x/2}^{L_x/2}| \mathcal{E}_x|^2dx}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\mathcal{E}_x|^2dx}$$
Therefore my question is how to reconcile the two facts that no power is transmitted into medium 2 and existence of power in medium 2 carried by the evanescent wave ?

Comment: You can find more info and links on the wikipedia page for TIR (total internal reflexion), under the [FTIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection#Frustrated_total_internal_reflection) (frustrated  TIR) section. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It's a "tunneling" behavior.  In effect, all the light is "pulled back" into the medium **unless** there's another body of high-index (well higher than the $n_1 = 1$ ) material within the distance covered by the evanescent wave.  If that material is close enough, then that part of the evanescent wave, which you can view as a probability wave, is in a region where the light itself can again manifest (because $n_1 and n_3 $ are such that total internal reflection between these two materials will not happen at the existing incidence angle).

So, no power is **transmitted** by medium 2, but the wave function is still nonzero there.

The same  mathematics which govern electrons tunneling out of quantum wells works just as well here, BTW

### edit :

I should have written that no power is transmitted perpendicular to the interface.  As several comments point out, energy can be carried *parallel* to the interface in medium 2, as happens in the cladding of optical fibers.

Comment: In the course of the "pulling back", it turns out that power *is* being transmitted inside the medium 2, but the direction of propagation is parallel to the surface.  There is no refracted wave propagating *into* medium 2.

Comment: @garyp good point.  I should have made that clearer.

Comment: You can actually integrate the Poynting vector in the evanescent direction and you will get zero...

Comment: If the material is close enough and the evanescent wave reaches it and produces another refracted wave at the second boundary, then how can no energy be transferred by the evanescent in the second medium since it produces a wave in the third medium(creates energy propagation without transferring energy there?)?

Comment: I think it is not true to write "no power is transmitted by medium 2". AFAIK even the cladding carries part of the energy. The difference is that in an ideal fiber (i.e. straight, smooth, dissipation-less, thick-cladded), the energy propagates along its axis only, and not from the core to the cladding. In other words, once the evanescent wave exists, even though it is *outside the core*, it does not remove  any energy from the guided mode.

Comment: (Note that e.g. surface plasmons are in fact two sandwiched evanescent waves - and they obviously carry a lot of energy along the interface.)

Comment: @Carl Witthoft Can you reference sources where it is proven theoretically? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MsTais I'm not sure what you're asking for.  Any textbook on quantum optics,  or introduction to waveguides, should have the  theoretical foundations.